# Sending External Parameters in json to pass onto to the api via webhook in dialogflow

Tags: javascript, ajax, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am calling an AJAX post request on /query endpoint of dialogflow and I want to send some parameters from the localStorage of the javascript.

```
    var baseUrl = “https: //api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910”
    $("#spokenResponse").addClass(“is - active”).find(".spoken-response__text").html(output);
$.ajax({
    type: “POST”,
    url: baseUrl + “query”,
    contentType: “application / json;charset = utf - 8”,
    dataType: “json”,
    headers: {“
        Authorization”: "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        query: text,
        lang: “en”,
        sessionId: sessid.toString()
    }),

    success: function(data) {
        prepareResponse(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        respond(messageInternalError);
    }
});
```

Please help me on how to send custom parameters in the request like say city or some id I got from the page. Thank you.

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. Did you find an answer to it ?

Comment: No. I did not. I abandoned the project anyways. I do not think you can send custom parameters though, based on my search.